# Write once run anywhere browser plugin tool/framework/language?

Tags: cross-platform, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, browser-plugin, browser-extension

I'm looking to create a browser plugin which would run in all of the major browsers, the only problem is that it seems I have to re-create the plugin in every browser.  Is there some tool or framework or language I can write a plugin with where it will automatically work on all major browsers?

All I need the button to do is scrape webpage content off the active page and from a few of the linked pages, then send it to a program with sockets or named pipes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done in linux, if it's only Windows that's fine.

Comment: Is the plugin you're trying to create something that definitely cannot be done in something like Java or Flash?

Comment: It has 1 purpose.  Scrape the current page which will be search results.  The search takes time so I can't re-run the search if I get just the search query, and the result page it seems isn't cached.  I could do this through java but then the user would have to open a seperate program which is a real pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe these "frameworks" can help you:

[FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/)

[Juce](https://www.juce.com/)