# Porting a Firefox Add-ons extension to Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, porting

I have developed a small Firefox Add-ons extension (Javascript+Xul+i18n support) published on [Mozilla Add-ons](http://addons.mozilla.org) repository and I would like to port it to Chrome.

Are you aware of any tool that could help me to port it from Firefox to Chrome?

Comment: Similar question, not quite a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823635/write-once-run-anywhere-browser-plugin-tool-framework-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/1807/) is your addon, you'll have to redesign it entirely. Chrome does not allow extensions to add entries to the context menu.

Comment: that's ok, I use keyboard more than mouse so cutting the *context menu* feature is really not a problem. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @systempuntoout The only UI elements you can add to are inside the URL area or in a collapsible right next to it; they can act on click (and optionally open a bubble with HTML in it).

Comment: are you aware of any porting tools?