# Porting Firefox Add-on to Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, porting, package.json, manifest.json

I have a Firefox Add-on that I need to port to Chrome. What steps would I need to follow?

I am trying to construct a Chrome's manifest.json file from Firefox's package.json, but I cannot find "main" entry in manifest.json. Whats the replacement for this in Chrome's manifest.json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Porting a Firefox Add-ons extension to Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662596/porting-a-firefox-add-ons-extension-to-google-chrome)

Comment: Thanks. I checked that before but it doesn't have much detail. I have figured it out that the Add-on I need to port is built using the Add-on SDK. I am now converting it to WebExtension. After that it would be easier to port. Am I right with my understanding?